# How can I bind a List to a ListView in Xamarin Android C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, listview, xamarin

I want to bind a ListView to a List called Users. The list Contains 1 column called: Name. Now I want to display all the names in the ListView, but the .DataSource doesn't work here! Is there another way?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/list-view/part-2-populating-a-list-view/

Comment: Thanks, but there is nothing on that site to add a list to a ListView. When I use the first example with string Items [], it says: "Cannot convert List to string"

Comment: either convert your List to an Array and use the built in ArrayAdapter, or create a custom ListAdapter that will work with your List